# mysql workbench не может импортировать дамп

Tags: mysql, sql, резервное-копирование, dump

В **mysql workbench -> server ->data export** делаю дамп, затем этот дамп пытаюсь восстановить через **mysql workbench -> server ->data import** процесс начинается, и не заканчивается:

```
import is running...
"пустая полоска"
Satus:
starting

11:09:10 Restoring DB (001)
Running: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe" --defaults-file="c:\users\harj\appdata\local\temp\tmps9_qx6.cnf"  --protocol=tcp --host=localhost --user=root --port=3306 --default-character-set=utf8 --comments --database=DB < "C:\\exp\\d.sql"

---------------------------------------
```

Через командную строку все отрабатывает, но надо что бы работало и в worckbench'e. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с такой вакханалией и как её разрешить?

Comment: Какой объём файла? Сколько ждали? Системный процесс наблюдали, не "зависает"?

Comment: Как бы все стандартно. Дело в workbench, потому что через консоль (cmd) все прекрасно импортируется... видимо баг. Хотя я версию обновил. На другой системе все окей.